# Turn off responsive behavior for Bootstrap 3

Tags: bootstrap-theme

I know [how to turn off responsive in bootrap](http://bigwilliam.com/turn-off-responsive-behavior-for-bootstrap-3/) . but how it can be in drupal theme. As i am using [Drupal Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) and created a subtheme. can that subtheme be non-responsive ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset Media queries breakpoints, it will not work.
Here is path: bootstrap/bootstrap_subtheme/less/variable.less
at line number 209.

Check it.

Comment: you will have to disable & enable theme.